# Removing stopwords from a string with ordered set and join retains a single stopword

Tags: python, nlp

I don't understand why I don't remove the stopword "a" in this loop. It seems so obvious that this should work...

Given a list of stop words, write a function that takes a string and returns a string stripped of the stop words. Output: stripped_paragraph = 'want figure out how can better data scientist'

1. Below I define 'stopwords'
2. I split all the words by a space, make a set of words while retaining the order
3. loop through the ordered and split substring set ('osss' var) and conditionally remove each word if it's a word in the list 'stopwords'

   ```
   paragraph = 'I want to figure out how I can be a better data scientist'
   def rm_stopwards(par):
       stopwords = ['I', 'as', 'to', 'you', 'your','but','be', 'a']
       osss = list(list(dict.fromkeys(par.split(' ')))) # ordered_split_shortened_set
       for word in osss:
           if word.strip() in stopwords:
               osss.remove(word)
           else:
               next
       return ' '.join(osss)
   print("stripped_paragraph = "+"'"+(rm_stopwards(paragraph))+"'")
   ```

My **incorrect** output is: 'want figure out how can a better data scientist'

**Correct output**: 'want figure out how can better data scientist'

edit: note that .strip() in the condition check with word.strip() is unnecessary and I still get the same output, that was me checking to make sure there wasn't an extra space somehow

edit2: this is an interview question, so I can't use any imports

Comment: Have you considered using nltk for this task?

Comment: You should not change(delete/add) the container(osss) while iterating over it.

Comment: @AmitVikramSingh yeah, I get that, GerardHPille's fix makes sense, but I still don't get why my second list(list(...)) doesn't fix that issue...

Comment: @jbflow, this is an answer for an interview question, see edit2

Comment: @ctde Your list(list(...)) doesn't fix the issue because you are using the same var osss to iterate and delete. When you put x = list(osss), then there are two lists, one is osss and new one is x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
paragraph = 'I want to figure out how I can be a better data scientist'

def rm_stopwards(par):
 stopwords = ['I', 'as', 'to', 'you', 'your','but','be', 'a']
 osss = list(list(dict.fromkeys(par.split(' ')))) # ordered_split_shortened_set
 x = list(osss)
 for word in osss:
    if word.strip() in stopwords:
        x.remove(word)
    #else:
    #    next
 ret = ' '.join(x)
 return ret

print("stripped_paragraph = "+"'"+(rm_stopwards(paragraph))+"'")
```

Comment: I'm changing this to be the right answer because it address the issue with my code instead of overwriting what I have with something new---albeit I'm definitely keeping jbflow's answer for studying reasons

Answer (score 3):

What your trying to do can be achieved with much fewer lines of code.

The main problem in your code is your changing the list while iterating over it.

This works and is much simpler. Essentially looping over the list of your paragraph words, and only keeping the ones that aren't in the stopwords list. Then joining them back together with a space.

```
paragraph = 'I want to figure out how I can be a better data scientist'
stopwords = ['I', 'as', 'to', 'you', 'your','but','be', 'a']
filtered = ' '.join([word for word in paragraph.split() if word not in stopwords])
print(filtered)
```

You may also consider using nltk, which has a predefined list of stopwords.

Answer (score 2):

You should not change(delete/add) a collection(osss) while iterating over it.

```
del_list = []
for word in osss:
    if word.strip() in stopwords:
        del_list.append(word)
    else:
        next
osss = [e for e in osss if e not in del_list]
```

Comment: Why doesn't the second list call in list(list(...)) correct for this issue?

Comment: Think about what's happening once you assign the list to variable osss, after assignment you are iterating over osss and also deleting from it. 
Now in the answer of @Gerard, he is creating a new list(osss) and assigning it to x, NOTE that osss and x are reference to two different lists. Deleting from x won't delete from osss, so you can iterate over osss and delete from x.